# Ayuda con este problema en C

Tags: c, array

Os dejo por aquí el código de un vector que he hecho pero no tengo ni idea de por qué no hace lo que debería.

He puesto una variable llamada `cantidad`, y un `vector[cantidad]` para que el usuario pueda manejar los valores del arreglo pero solo mete hasta 6 valores.

*Por ejemplo: ¿Cuántos valores quieres en el arreglo?: 7 , pues introduce hasta 6..*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("ARRAY VARIABLE\n\n");

    int cantidad;
    int vector[cantidad];

    printf("Introduzca la cantidad de valores del array: ");
    scanf("%d",&cantidad);

    for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
    {
        printf("%d valor del array: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&vector[i]);
    }

    printf("\nValores introducidos\n\n");   
    for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
    {
        printf("  %d",vector[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En internet, el uso de mayúsculas se considera equivalente a gritar. Te invito a corregir tu pregunta, usando el botón "editar".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int cantidad;
int vector[cantidad];
```

Fíjate que en esas dos lineas de código... estas definiendo el vector. y el tamaño. Pero nunca estas definiendo cuanto vale cantidad. Y lo que defines después, no soluciona el problema, porque vector ya esta dimensionado. Por lo tanto, debes definir vector, después de saber cuanto vale cantidad. Y te deja ingresar 6 o 7 o 9 milagrosamente.

o sea.. tu código debería ir así:

```
printf("Introduzca la cantidad de valores del array: ");
scanf("%d",&cantidad);
int vector[cantidad];
```

Comment: Es verdad, que lógico, no se como no me he dado cuenta, muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)

Comment: Ojo, que esto es un VLA, que no está soportado en C (salvo por extensión del compilador) desde C99.